# How to Distribute Jenkins Slave Containers Within Docker Swarm

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-swarm

I would like to have my Jenkins master (not containerized) to create slaves within a container. So I have installed the docker plugin into jenkins, created a docker server, configured and jenkins does indeed spin up a slave container fine after the job creation. [image]

However, after I have created another docker server and created a swarm out of two of them and tried running jenkins jobs again it have continued to only deploy containers on the original server(which is now also a manager). I'd be expecting the swarm to balance the load and to distribute the newly created containers evenly across the swarm. What am I missing?

Do I have to use a service perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of that moment there was nothing I could find in the swarm that would help me to manipulate container distribution across the swarm nodes.

Ended up using a more flexible kubernetes for that purpose. I think marathon is capable of that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Docker images by themselves are not load balanced even if deployed in a swarm. What you're looking for would indeed be a Service definition. Just be careful because of port allocation. If you're deploying your jenkins slaves to listen on port 80, etc, **all swarm hosts** will listen on port 80 and mesh route to the containers.

Basically means you couldn't deploy anything else to port 80 on those hosts. Once that's done, however, any requests to the hosts would be load balanced to the containers.

The other nice thing is that you can dynamically change the number of replicas with service update

```
docker service update JenkinsService --replicas 42
```

While 42 may be extreme, you could obviously change it :)